# Firebase Header CSP Rules

Tags: firebase, content-security-policy, firebase-hosting

So I know that I can add CSP in the `<meta>` on my website. However, I read that it is better to add these to your HTTP header. I checked in the Firebase docs and see the following:

> We currently support the following headers as a key:
>   ...Content-Security-Policy.

However, I can't find any example on how to format the rules in the file. I could be overthinking this, but how do I add rules to my Firebase headers that would cover this:

```
Refused to load the script 'data:application/javascript;base64,dmFyIHVyY2hpblRyYWNrZXI9ZnVuY3Rpb24oKXt9…RUcmFja2VyQnlOYW1lOiBmdW5jdGlvbigpe190cmFja0V2ZW50OiBmdW5jdGlvbigpe319fTs=' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://f.vimeocdn.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://js-agent.newrelic.com https://bam.nr-data.net https://f.vimeocdn.com".
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Firebase Hosting doesn't enforce the formatting of your headers, so to get the exact results you want you'll just want to figure out how to format the header. [This guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/) looks to be pretty comprehensive and can help you get started.

To actually apply the CSP headers to your Firebase Hosting site, you'll want to alter your `firebase.json`. For example:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "headers": [{
      "source":"**",
      "headers": [
        {"key":"Content-Security-Policy","value":"script-src 'self'"}
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

See [the Firebase Hosting docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-headers) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. I'd like to see an example of how this file could b extended, e.g. to add frame-src to a second domain and style-src to a third.

Comment: Firebase Hosting does not have ways to conditionally change headers based on hostname -- a given site will serve the same content regardless of which custom domain it's being served from, for instance. However, you can add additional components to this header by separating each declaration with a semicolon as per [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy).